# How to pass from and size back in query response

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch search query which gets the documents in paginated fashion, it is as below:

```
{
    "from" : 5, "size" : 2,
    "sort" : [
        { "title" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ],
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "_source": ["title"]
}
```

I would like to get `from` and `size` back in the response from ES which isn't currently returned from the above query.
Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: You could also write a very simple and straightforward plugin for this,take a look at the JVM-example in the elasticsearch for reference. Just add a new rest handler, execute and get the search response as a string and then append the from and size parameters to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES does not currently return the pagination parameters that have been sent in the request. You need to hack it... or submit a [feature request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/new)

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) in order to pass that information in pretty much any queries, however, you'll need to wait until ES 5 for `match_all` to support named queries:

```
{
    "from" : 5, "size" : 2,
    "sort" : [
        { "title" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ],
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {"_name": "5:2"}  <--- name the query with the from/size params
    },
    "_source": ["title"]
}
```

In the response, you'll get `"5:2"` back which you can parse to figure out what `from` and `size` were.

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "test": "test"
        },
        "matched_queries": [       <--- you can find from/size here
          "5:2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```